# Setting the build status to failed when failingFast

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

In a declarative jenkins pipeline, when failFast is used within a set of parallel stages. How do you set the build status to 'FAILED' instead of 'ABORTED'?

Assuming something fails, this will exit with 'ABORTED'

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Parallel') {
            failFast true
            parallel {
                stage('Branch A') {
                    steps {
                        sh "foo"
                    }
                }
                stage('Branch B') {
                    steps {
                        sh "bar"
                    }
                }
                stage('Branch C') {
                    steps {
                        sh "baz"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If FailFast is removed the build will eventually fail with 'FAILED'. But I need the FailFast behaviour as well.

Answer (score 1):

OK, after a bit of investigation this appears to an issue with Jenkins: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-55459

I was able to get by this by adding a script with a try/catch to those steps within the parallel stages.

```
steps {
     script {

          try {
               MyCode()
          }
          catch (Exception err) {
               if (currentBuild.result == null) {
                    error "The stage '${env.STAGE_NAME}' has failed."
               } else {
                    echo "Exiting stage early."
               }
           }
     }
}
```

Comment: About your now deleted answer, you asked a separate moderation-related question in it by editing roughly 5 hours ago: you can't comment until you have 50 rep, or upvote 'til you have 15. That's how the current rep system works, and it's mainly to avoid abuse, although it's probably frustrating for new users with no intention of abusing it. Getting there is pretty easy though, it takes 5 upvotes on answers to unlock both (assuming you don't get downvoted)